# Combinatorial proof - ladder problem - take 1 or two steps at a time

Tags: combinatorics

A ladder consists of 12 steps . A man wants to go up through the ladder. He may take 1 or two steps at a time or any combination of these two . Find the total number of ways he can go up .

This question is taken from [here](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=1838#top) and answer given says, as the number of steps increases, the solution goes as fibonacci numbers,
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987,

But, can anybody please provide a combinatorics proof for this or this fibonacci numbers algorithm is the only standard way of solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n$ denote the number of ways the fellow can get to step $n$.  Look at the last step; by definition it must be either $1$ or $2$.  If $1$, then he got to step $a_{n-1}$ and stepped $1$.  If $2$ then he got to $a_{n-2}$ and stepped $2$.  Hence we have the recursion $$a_{n}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$$ which is the same recursion satisfied by the Fibonacci numbers.  All that remains is to compute $a_n$ for some small $n$, but that is not difficult.

Comment: so answer is 233 for the given question?

Comment: Yes, it is $233$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be the number of rungs on the ladder. For $n=0$ and $n=1$, there is exactly one way to climb the ladder. For $n>1$, the man may climb $n-1$ rungs, and then take one step, or climb $n-2$ rungs, then skip one. This exhausts all possibilities, so if $F(n)$ counts the number of ways to climb $n$ rungs, $F(n) = F(n-1)+F(n-2)$.

Comment: so answer is 233 for the given question?